# push overwriting previous ui-grid rowdata

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Using angular ui grid I have included a button to the left of every row that when clicked would add the row to the cart, duplicate rows can be added to the cart so I get milliseconds to make each row unique, however each click of my cart button on row one is overwriting the previous row entry, I have tried initializing a new array but that isn't working either.

Please see JSFIDDLE below for working demo

**JS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid']);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {

var productData = {
    "Products": [{
        "TagLevel1": null,
        "ProductName": "Carrot",
        "ProductCode": "car-001",
        "IsSelected": null,
        "ClientLineId": null,
        "Active": true
    }, {
        "TagLevel1": null,
        "ProductName": "Cucumber",
        "ProductCode": "cuc-001",
        "IsSelected": null,
        "ClientLineId": null,
        "Active": true
    }, {
        "TagLevel1": null,
        "ProductName": "Cabbage",
        "ProductCode": "cab-001",
        "IsSelected": null,
        "ClientLineId": null,
        "Active": true
    }, {
        "TagLevel1": null,
        "ProductName": "Lettuce",
        "ProductCode": "let-001",
        "IsSelected": null,
        "ClientLineId": null,
        "Active": true
    }]
};

var actionTemplate = '<div style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;line-height:35px;"><button id="{{row.entity.ProductId + \'_AddToCartBtn\'}}" title="Add to cart" ng-class="(row.entity.IsSelected == true ? \'iconBtnClicked iconBtnClick fa fa-cart-plus fa-2x\':\'iconBtn iconBtnClick fa fa-shopping-cart fa-2x\')" ng-click="grid.appScope.AddToCart(row.entity, $event)" /></div>';

  $scope.gridOptions = {
        rowHeight: 35,
    showGridFooter: false,
        enableFiltering: false,
        enableColumnMenus: false,
        columnDefs: [
            { field: 'IsSelected', name: 'IsSelected', width: '85', displayName: 'ACTION', enableSorting: false, enableFiltering:false, cellTemplate: actionTemplate },
            { field: 'ProductCode', name: 'ProductCode', width: '200', displayName: 'PRODUCT CODE'  },
      { field: 'ProductName', name: 'ProductName', width: '800', displayName: 'PRODUCT NAME' },
        ],
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        }
    };

  $scope.init = function() {
    $scope.ProductViewModel = productData;
    $scope.gridOptions.data = $filter('orderBy')($scope.ProductViewModel.Products, "ProductCode", false);
    $scope.ProductViewModel.Products = [];
  };



  //button on GUI represented with a cart icon on each row, when clicked, add the product to the cart
    $scope.AddToCart = function(rowData, event) {
        rowData.IsSelected = true
        rowData.ClientLineId = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();
        console.log('ClientIdUsed:' + rowData.ClientLineId);

        $scope.ProductViewModel.Products.push(rowData);
        console.log('PVM.Products: ' + JSON.stringify($scope.ProductViewModel.Products));
    };

  $scope.init();
}]);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please see fiddle demo:
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/g5vfvn1d/) I am writing the array to the console.

**UPDATE**

I got it to work by doing this:

```
$scope.AddToCart = function(rowData, event) {
    $scope.ProductViewModel.Products.push({"TagLevel1":null,"ProductName":rowData.ProductName, "ProductCode":rowData.ProductCode, "IsSelected": true, "ClientLineId": new Date().getUTCMilliseconds(), "Active":rowData.Active, "$$hashKey":rowData.$$hashKey });
    console.log('PVM.Products: ' + JSON.stringify($scope.ProductViewModel.Products));
};
```

Is there a cleaner (more maintainable) way?

**EDIT**

The final array in the console (if I click the cabbage row 4 times) should look like this:

```
[{"TagLevel1":null,"ProductName":"Cabbage","ProductCode":"cab-001","IsSelected":true,"ClientLineId":142,"Active":true,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0007"},{"TagLevel1":null,"ProductName":"Cabbage","ProductCode":"cab-001","IsSelected":true,"ClientLineId":285,"Active":true,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0007"},{"TagLevel1":null,"ProductName":"Cabbage","ProductCode":"cab-001","IsSelected":true,"ClientLineId":376,"Active":true,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0007"},{"TagLevel1":null,"ProductName":"Cabbage","ProductCode":"cab-001","IsSelected":true,"ClientLineId":962,"Active":true,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0007"}]
```

*Notice the unique ClientLineId's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by creating a new object and the looping the keys and values into the new object on each click.

```
$scope.AddToCart = function(rowData, event) {
    rowData.IsSelected = true;
    var newObj = {};
    $.each(Object.keys(rowData), function(i,v){
        if(v === "ClientLineId")
        newObj[v] = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();
        else if(v === "IsSelected")
        newObj[v] = true;
        else
        newObj[v] = rowData[v];
    });
    $scope.ProductViewModel.Products.push(newObj);
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.ProductViewModel.Products));
};
```

See [FIXED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/g5vfvn1d/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Your **$scope.ProductViewModel.Products** and **$scope.gridOptions.data** does not reference to the same array.

Please see the fixed fiddle:

```
$scope.init = function() {
    $scope.ProductViewModel = productData;
    $scope.ProductViewModel.Products = $filter('orderBy')($scope.ProductViewModel.Products, "ProductCode", false);
    $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.ProductViewModel.Products;
};
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/g5vfvn1d/3/)

Comment: Thanks for trying but that wasn't what I was wanting, I don't want the clicked row to be re-added to the same grid, I just want it to use my clientLineId and eventually print to a different grid, for now I just want to see it printing to the console with the unique clientlineid every time I click the same row. I just happen to be using  $scope.ProductViewModel.Products for this example but push it into something like  $scope.ProductViewModel.SelectedProducts, this array should have only the row clicked multiple times with a different clientline id, hope that makes sense.

Comment: It's ok. I'll delete the answer later.